# How to play videos according to the buttons pressed in same video view in another activity?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have two activities.

In first activity I have placed five buttons. Each button represent different cartoon videos to be played when pressed.

In my second activity I have added `VideoView`. Now I want that when I press a certain button, it should play the related video in the video view.

In short, I want to play different videos in a single video view. Instead to adding multiple video views for each cartoon video button.

Comment: Can you show the code of VideoView which you've used please.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you
just put some extra data in your intent instance like this;

```
Kotlin code -->

val intent = Intent(this@FirstActivity , SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("videoNum" , videoNumber /*base on clicked button send 
0|1|2|3|4|5 or some another integer value*/)
startActivity(intent)
```

and in SecondActiviity onCreate method :

```
val videoNumber = intent.getIntExtra("videoNum",defalutValue // maybe 0)
```

now use videoNumber to indicate which button has been clicked